# Thinkpad battery not charging when AC adaptor connected

Tags: 18.04, battery, thinkpad

Bought a refurb Lenovo t540p which I ordered with no drive so I could install Ubuntu on to it straight away and use a drive that I have laying around.
Turns out I'm having the problem where the battery doesn't always charge when the AC adaptor is connected. The only solution I'm finding right now is what seems to be a pretty well known procedure

- Shut down computer
- Pull out the adapter, then battery
- plug the adaptor back in and wait 30 seconds. Turn the computer back on
- uninstall Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control.
- Turn off the computer and pull out adaptor
- Put battery back in laptop
- Put adaptor back in laptop
- Wait 30 sec and turn back on
- Battery charges again

This goes well until I let the computer run on battery and the plug it in again (not always). Another way to reproduce the problem is to reboot the computer while running on battery only.
 My guess is that I need an Ubuntu counterpart for step 5, which I obviously can't do since it's windows.

And this is where I seem to be stuck. All that I seem to find it to install TLP, but this seems to have some power management configurations and is action-wise very unlike step 5. So any help for finding a permanent situation without having to install windows is much appreciated.